# For iPad apps, how to build an app so that it can be the Production release to see its final speed?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a way to build for the Production version of an iPad app, so that `NSLog` won't print anything out, and higher optimization level is used for the compiler, and no debugging information is put into the code, etc?

I tried `Product -> Build for -> Archiving` and also for `Profiling`, and chose `Product -> Perform Action -> Run without building`, but I still see the messages from `NSLog` and it looks like it is a debug build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Edit your Schema for Release,instead of debug.
That will do.
But The NSLog will work even in release,if you don't switch it of yourself like here [Do I need to disable NSLog before release Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025471/do-i-need-to-disable-nslog-before-release-application)

Comment: so set "Release" for the "Run" build or for whatever build you would like?  But after that still `NSLog` messages were being generated..., and also breakpoint still will stop the code execution...

Comment: The NSLog will work even in release,if you don't switch it of yourself like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025471/do-i-need-to-disable-nslog-before-release-application

Comment: thanks.  funny NSLog has no mechanism to be turned off from the build type itself (we need to implement it)