# Remove NSLog from Release Builds

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it true that one should not use NSLog() on production code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300673/is-it-true-that-one-should-not-use-nslog-on-production-code)
>   [Do I need to disable NSLog before release Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025471/do-i-need-to-disable-nslog-before-release-application)

I need to remove all the NSLOGs which are present in my project during the Release build. I have tried using the below code , but still accessing the build via phone, still NSLOG shows up in the console.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define debug_NSLog(format, ...) NSLog(format, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define debug_NSLog(format, ...)
#endif
```

Comment: Are you using `debug_NSLog` in your code in place of `NSLog`?

Comment: Please assign the Constant value into the .pch file and assign the boolean value and check weather the value is true then display other wise not display.

Comment: May your answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300673/is-it-true-that-one-should-not-use-nslog-on-production-code

Answer (score 13):

To simply remove NSLogs:

```
#define NSLog(s,...)
```

A `#define` without a substitution specified will substitute nothing, deleting anything that matches that `#define`. This works with simple token defines and with function-like defines like the above.

Comment: I have used this "#define NSLog(s,...)" , but still running the app in the RELEASE MODE within the device, still NSLOG comes in the console.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code

```
#ifdef DEBUGGING
# define DBLog(fmt,...) NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:(fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__]);
#else
# define DBLog(...)
#endif
```

Make sure the compiler flags are properly set.

Also, when you checked the console, did you check if you were using release mode ?

Comment: This is pretty much functionally equivalent to the OPs `debug_NSLog`.  How does this answer the OPs question?

Comment: may be he missed setting the compiler flag or build was in debug mode when he checked the console, which I have mentioned .

Comment: This is another way, and i find this easy being in the current state of my app release:
#ifndef DEBUG
  #define NSLog(...) /* suppress NSLog when in release mode */
#endif

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define NSLog(fmt,...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#define NSLog(...)
#endif
```

This will print `NSLog` if you are running it on simulator..

Comment: many devs are testing and debugging on actual devices not sims, but it could be useful for some.