# Disable NSLog for a specific class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nslog

I know how you can disable **all** `NSLog` messages from answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969130/how-to-print-out-the-method-name-and-line-number-and-conditionally-disable-nslog) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025471/do-i-need-to-disable-nslog-before-release-application).

It's yet unclear to me what should I define in my `.pch` file to conditionally disable `NSLog` in a separate class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i use the following log macros for similar stuff. You can define `NO_LOG` to whatever files you want to skip from loging (comma-separated).

```
#define MAKESTRING(__VA_ARGS__) #__VA_ARGS__
#define TOSTRING(...) MAKESTRING(__VA_ARGS__)

static inline void PxReportv(BOOL doLog, char const *file, int line, NSString *prefix, NSString *fmt, va_list argList) {
    if (doLog) {
        NSString *fileNameWithExtension = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", file] lastPathComponent]; 
#ifdef NO_LOG
        NSString *fileName = [fileNameWithExtension stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        char *f = TOSTRING(NO_LOG);
        NSArray *comps = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", f] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        for (NSString *except in comps) {
            if ([except isEqualToString:fileName]) {
                return;
            }
        }
#endif
        vprintf([[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ <%@ [%d]> %@\n", prefix, fileNameWithExtension, line, fmt] arguments:argList] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], NULL);
    }
}

static inline void PxReport(BOOL doLog, char const *file, int line, NSString *prefix, NSString *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    PxReportv(doLog, file, line, prefix, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

#define PxError(...) PxReport(YES, __FILE__, __LINE__, @"[ERROR]", __VA_ARGS__)

#ifdef DEBUG
    #define PxDebug(...) PxReport(YES, __FILE__, __LINE__, @"[DEBUG]", __VA_ARGS__)
    #define NSLog(...) PxReport(YES, __FILE__, __LINE__, @"", __VA_ARGS__)
#else
    #define PxDebug(...)
    #define NSLog(...)
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

Use

`#define NSLog //`

It will comment all your logs if it's one liner

OR use

`#define NSLog(...)`

Comment: How about not ALL, but in a specific class?

Comment: Put this #define in that file. Don't put it in .pch file

Comment: NO one says that,,, and few people are just against me :(   At least  We can remove our answers from here... :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya but before down voting one should specify why he/she has down voted. It's not that our answers are always right there may be something wrong with and I'm open to hear that. Anyways this is correct as far as I'm concerned :)

Comment: Yes I know, Even mine was just similar to you, you have noticed, i also got -1, now i removed. and now i remeber by name 3 people who downvotes, abuses without a proper explanation as they have 30K, 50K points.... and we are in 6K :p