# How to find NSLog "Hit Request String" or "Hit Parameters" in ADMS iOs

Tags: ios, nslog, ios-frameworks

I'm on working on a project that using ADMS in iOS and I find something annoying like this in LOG:

```
    2013-05-01 21:20:12.265 MyProject[1550:907] Hit Parameters : {
       c =     {
           a = "    {
               AppID = MyProject (1.0) 
               CarrierName = (null) 
               LaunchEvent = LaunchEvent 
               DaysSinceLastUse = 0 
               DayOfWeek = 4 
               OSEnvironment = iOS 6.0 
               HourOfDay = 21 
               Launches = 10 
               DaysSinceFirstUse = 0 
               DeviceName = iPad2,1 
               Resolution = 768x1024 
               OSVersion = iOS 6.0 
               CrashEvent = CrashEvent 
           }";
       };
       ce = "UTF-8";
       pageName = "MyProject (1.0) Launch";
       pe = "lnk_o";
       pev2 = "ADMS BP Event";
       t = "1/4/2013 21:20:12 3 -420";
       ts = 3215461324;
       vid = 9886576TG6129HJSLKA71923;
   }
```

What caused and where I can find that NSLog? Because it disrupts my application and makes the process very slow.

Btw I'm using **admsAppLibrary.a** as a framework for **omniture** in my application.

Thank you.

Comment: Set a symbolic breakpoint on `NSLog` (sans parenthesis), and see.

Comment: May be this answer will helpful for you.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025471/do-i-need-to-disable-nslog-before-release-application/2025764#2025764

Answer (score 0):

ADMS_Measurement *measurement = [ADMS_Measurement sharedInstance];
measurement.debugLogging = YES;