# Submit first iOS app. What do i have to do?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, app-store

i'm goind to submit my first iOS app right now,

I removed every `NSLog`.but i'm wondering if i have to remove all comment  : `//` an `/* */`.Performance will be affected if i do not remove comment ? (there is a lot of comment)

and what generally should i take care of ?

Do i need to include the a certificate for push notification ?

Where do i set the language of my app, i want it to be French, so i have set in the info.plist 
Localization native development region  to France, nevertheless i still have the "done" button when playing video instead of "Terminé" in French !

Thanks to all, i'll take any advices !

Comment: no need for smilies in question

Comment: You do not need to remove comments. They don't affect the performance of your app or any code in general. You can add as many as you want.

Comment: Thank you ! Does anyone knows why i do not get the button in French (also working for Copy/Paste from textfield menu)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Congratulations. Getting apps approved by Apple can be a painful thing, however, experience, some rejects and some patience will only make you good.

1. //Comments do not affect the performance of a compiled app. you can keep them
2. NSLogs don't really compromise the performance, but they write on the device's local log. You may want to comment them or keep the meaningful ones only: http://www.cimgf.com/2009/01/24/dropping-nslog-in-release-builds/
3. Internal language of your app is defined by you. Info.plist needs to be set
4. Make sure you have ALL icon dimensions set. They easily reprove if something is missing
5. Make sure you have iPhone5-sized screenshots at iTunes Connect
6. Make sure the description and keywords you enter at iTunes Connect are appropriate
7. If you use background GPS or some kind of "special" or hidden feature, they will force you to mention it in your app description. Also, properly set your info.plist with "required background modes" if you're using anything "fancy" such as background GPS, VOIP, audio, etc.
8. Make sure your development and distribution certificates are all setup and valid
9. Make sure you're making the final build with your distribution cert
10. Push certificates stay in your server, they're not uploaded with your app (are you using push at all?)
11. After upload received, expect one week for approval (or not)
12. Expect unreasonable and crazy reasons for them to reject something (it happens!)
13. If they reject, it's not the end of the world. You can always change/fix and send again
14. Make sure your bundle identifier is correct and matches everything else (com.example.etc)
15. Make sure your nibs/storyboards reflect the screen size of the minimum device version you're stating

In general, I would be more concerned with the items **4** and **5** above. Good luck!

Comment: What about warnings when i do not declare an IBAction or a method into .h ?

Comment: It works, but why not doing things clean and nice? Depending on the warning, you should try to solve them. Memory leaks for example... You should use the Instruments that come with Xcode to see how the memory is going. I assume you properly dealloc things when they need to be.

Comment: i'm using ARC, no need of deaaloc no ?

Comment: In theory, everything that is not auto-dealloc or released, which takes memory and is not being used, should be freed up. I assume you've tested your app and used the Instruments to see if there are memory leaks. You can find interesting and revealing things there.

Warnings are not critical, but they're warnings.

Comment: ok thank you very much i'll give a try, but it is not so easy when you start, i've tried using instruments it is beautiful but i do not understant, but i'll give a try, thank you very much Jhon !

Answer (score 2):

Here is a blog post my friend shared with me. [Check List](http://sreecharans.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/checklist-for-submitting-app-to-app.html) Should be able to help you see what you have to do.

You dont need to remove the comments.

Comment: Nice blog ! Thanks for the tips Will !

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your app using Xcode or [Application Loader](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/9_UsingApplicationLoader/UsingApplicationLoader.html). Application Loader is a small Cocoa app that you will use to deliver your binary to Apple.

I suggest you to follow apple document , [Adding New Apps](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW1), you can find many more link over there.

Here is the nice [tutorial of Ray wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1)

Answer (score -2):

You dont need to remove `NSLog`.
You dont need to remove comments. Performance is not depends on comments.
If you didn't use push notification, why you are bothering about certificate for push notification ?
There is nice tutorial for app submission

[Ray wenderlich's blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1)

each and everything described in it.

You can set the uibutton's title as follows:

```
[btn setTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"done", "") forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Removing `NSLog` statements can be a good idea, having lots will slow down the app. Of course it can be useful to leave a few in there for debugging purposes.

Comment: @manujmv, please have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025471/do-i-need-to-disable-nslog-before-release-application. Removing NSLog is good thing. It affects performance.