# Disabling NSLog For Production In Swift Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

So this answer [Do I need to disable NSLog before release Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025471/do-i-need-to-disable-nslog-before-release-application) gives a great way to disable NSLog in a production environment, but unfortunately, this solution does not seem to work for Swift projects. My approach was to place the following code in the bridging header .h file that I am using for some pods in my project.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define DLog(...) NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__])
#else
    #define DLog(...) do { } while (0)
#endif
```

However, using DLog in Swift code is causing the compiler to state that they are unrecongnized symbols. Is there somewhere else I should be placing this `#ifdef` or is there a different solution for Swift project in general?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You'll need to set up a compiler flag to use the Swift preprocessor - go to the **Swift Compiler - Custom Flags** section of Build Settings to set up a `-D DEBUG` flag:

[image: DEBUG flag]

Then in your code you can define a `DLog()` function and only print your message if the `DEBUG` flag is set:

```
func DLog(message: String, function: String = #function) {
    #if DEBUG
    println("\(function): \(message)")
    #endif
}
```

Comment: I actually have already added the `-D DEBUG` flag, but thank you anyway. Where would you suggest I place this function so it can be seen globally? This approach looks interesting.

Comment: It can be in any file that is compiled with your module/application - in the AppDelegate.swift file is fine, or you can make a separate file for global constants, etc.

Comment: I guess we can count on the compiler to optimise out the empty function calls?

Comment: The provided `println()` (`print()` as of Swift 2.0) function accepts both `String` and `NSString` arguments. How can I achieve the same in the signature of `DLog()`?

Comment: Oh, forget it... I found the solution in the signature of print() on the documentation. See my answer.

Comment: I found another good article. https://www.marekbell.com/stripping-print-and-debugprint-in-swift-for-release-builds/ Explained where we shall put the code.

Comment: @CullenSUN Tried the method described at that link, but it didn't overtake any print calls at all.

Answer (score 9):

I am a pretty junior-level developer and need things defined a little more clearly to follow along at times. I had been having trouble with a similar issue, replacing println() instead, and when i asked that question my inquiry was marked as a duplicate of this question.

After lots of research, trial, error, error, error, and ERROR!!, I found that the sequence I needed to follow is:

1. Click on the project name at the top of the File Navigator at the left of the Xcode project window. This is line that has the name of the project, how many build targets there are, and the iOS SDK version.
2. Choose the **Build Settings** tab and scroll down to the "**Swift Compiler - Custom Flags**" section near the bottom. Click the Down Arrow next to **Other Flags** to expand the section.
3. Click on the **Debug** line to select it. Place your mouse cursor over the right side of the line and double-click. A list view will appear. Click the **+** button at the lower left of the list view to add a value. A text field will become active.
4. In the text field, enter the text `-D DEBUG` and press **Return** to commit the line.
5. Add a new Swift file to your project. You are going to want to make a custom class for the file, so enter text along the lines of the following:

   ```
   class Log {

      var intFor : Int

     init() {
       intFor = 42
     }

     func DLog(message: String, function: String = __FUNCTION__) {
       #if DEBUG
         println("\(function): \(message)")
       #endif
     }
   }
   ```

(I was having trouble getting the class init to be accepted by Xcode today, so the init may be a bit more heavyweight than necessary.)

6. Now you will need to reference your custom class in any class in which you intend to use the new custom function in place of `println()` Add this as a property in every applicable class:

   ```
      let logFor = Log()
   ```
7. Now you can replace any instances of `println()` with `logFor.DLog()`. The output also includes the name of the function in which the line was called.
8. Note that inside class functions I couldn't call the function unless I made a copy of the function as a class function in that class, and `println()` is also a bit more flexible with the input, so I couldn't use this in every instance in my code.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the Apple Swift blog entry on writing assert [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=4)

Briefly, the answer is to write DLog as:

```
func DLog(message:String, function:String = __FUNCTION__) {
#if !NDEBUG
    NSLog("%@, %@", function, message)
#endif
}
```

Comment: Where would you suggest I place this function so it's available globally? In my `AppDelegate`?

Comment: For stuff like this I generally create a separate file.  My version sits in "Logging.swift"  That way when I need it again, it's pretty easy to pick it up and drop it somewhere else.

Comment: Look like the most relevant answer. One thing to note is that as of Swift 3, `__FUNCTION__` is deprecated. Instead, `#function` should be used in place of `__FUNCTION__`.

Answer (score 2):

Below, I have modified the answer by Nate Cook given above. This version works with both `String` and `NSString` arguments:

```
func DLog<T>(message:T, function: String = __FUNCTION__) {
    #if DEBUG
        if let text = message as? String {

            print("\(function): \(text)")
        }
    #endif
}
```

It can be handy when you need to do something like this:

```
DLog("Received data:")
DLog(NSString(data:httpResponseBodyData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure magic `_isDebugAssertConfiguration()` does all stuff instead of the `Custom Flags`-related mess:

```
func log<T>(argument: T, file: String = #file, line: Int = #line, function: String = #function) {
    guard _isDebugAssertConfiguration() else {
        return
    }

    let fileName = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: file, isDirectory: false).URLByDeletingPathExtension?.lastPathComponent ?? "Unknown"

    print("\(fileName)@\(line)/\(function): \(argument)")
}
```

See more info (and options) about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34532569/496389 .

Answer (score 1):

```
#if DEBUG
#else
public func NSLog(_ format: String, _ args: CVarArg...)
{
    // noop
}
#endif
```

The quest leading to this: [swift debugPrint vs print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504865/swift-debugprint-vs-print/50531401#50531401)

Answer (score 0):

I just found this amazing global function:
https://gist.github.com/Abizern/a81f31a75e1ad98ff80d

This matches Nate Cook's answer and additionally prints the filename and line number of the encountered debug print statement.

Comment: Try to register the code here, because the link may become unavailable.

Comment: @uclagamer The way we do it on Stackoverflow is include code in answer, not just link to code somewhere else. That's why you were voted down, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with uclagamer's answer, which is essentially a souped up print function wrapped in a preprocessor conditional:

```
func gLog<T>(@autoclosure object: () -> T, _ file: String = __FILE__, _ function: String = __FUNCTION__, _ line: Int = __LINE__)
    {
    #if DEBUG
        let value = object()
        let stringRepresentation: String

        if let value = value as? CustomDebugStringConvertible
            {
            stringRepresentation = value.debugDescription
            }
        else if let value = value as? CustomStringConvertible
            {
            stringRepresentation = value.description
            }
        else
            {
            fatalError("gLog only works for values that conform to CustomDebugStringConvertible or CustomStringConvertible")
            }

        let fileURL = NSURL(string: file)?.lastPathComponent ?? "Unknown file"
        let queue = NSThread.isMainThread() ? "UI" : "BG"
        let gFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        gFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss:SSS"
        let timestamp = gFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

        print("\(timestamp) \(queue) = \(fileURL) | \(function)[\(line)]: " + stringRepresentation)
    #endif
    }
```

This is updated for Swift 2.0.  All credit goes to Abider Nasir.  His original blog post (and linked gist) can be found here:

http://abizern.org/2015/02/01/debug-logging-in-swift/

IMPORTANT NOTE: if anyone is struggling to find the "Swift Compiler - Custom Flags section of Build Settings", which has been mentioned many, many times, you need to make sure that "All" build settings are shown, not just the "Basic" build settings, as is the default.

[image]