# It is possible to access the console logs for an iOS App from AppStore?

Tags: swift, xcode, logging, console, production

I have an app on AppStore that logs sensitive data in the Xcode console using iOS default `print()` method.

My question is if those logs can be intercepted by someone else in one way or another using different softwares? Or should I release a new version of the app to the AppStore that disables console logs on Release environment.

It is recommended to disable the logs for Release version using `#if DEBUG`? Or should I not take care of this.

Comment: Also you can read more about print() slow execution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738943/does-print-println-slow-execution

Answer (score 1):

### Technical Q&A QA1747 Debugging Deployed iOS Apps

**Q:  How can I debug a deployed app without Xcode's debugger?**

> A: Once you have deployed your app, either through the App Store or as an Ad Hoc or Enterprise build, you won't be able to attach Xcode's debugger to it. To debug problems, you need to analyze Crash Logs and **Console output from the device**.
>
> Apple Watch crash logs will be available on the paired device and can also be obtained using the methods described below.
>
> For more information on writing rich NSLog statements, see Improved logging in Objective-C.

Courtesy of : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1747/_index.html

Comment: That's for `NSLog`, swift `print` statements don't show up in the device logs