# How to handle print statements when submitting app to app store

Tags: swift, app-store

I am working on submitting my first Swift app on app store and I was just curious on how to handle the print statements that I have in the app. For example

```
do {
    try managedObjectContext.save()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to leave the print staments in for final release. I don't think apple will reject an app with print statements but better to not have them for release.

What you can do is create  a global print func (new swift file or above any class) so your whole project can access it.

```
func print(items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") { 
    #if DEBUG
    Swift.print(items[0], separator:separator, terminator: terminator)   
    #endif
}
```

and call your print statements like normal

```
print("Hello")
```

You can also ignore the DEBUG flag and simply comment out the print line for release

```
func print(items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") { 
   //Swift.print(items[0], separator:separator, terminator: terminator)   
}
```

Comment: I already have "-D" and "COCOAPODS" in the list, how do i add custom flaag named "-D DEBUG" ?

Comment: I just updated my answer for some more detailed instructions, alternatively have a look at my github project.

Comment: How about overriding `print` function and quote it when i want to archive the app? I saw the answer by matt here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913799/remove-println-for-release-version-ios-swift?lq=1

Comment: Hey, not sure what you mean. I have read the link and one of the suggestion is basically what I am doing. I think it is the easiest

Comment: Read the matt answer, he said create a print method. `func print(items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    Swift.print(items[0], separator:separator, terminator: terminator)
}` and i don't know comment it in the archive the app action will help?

Comment: Yeah this is very cool. Its basically my way but without the struct. Thank you very much, I will update my answer to reflect this. I used to do this but it stopped working, now I know why. Thanks again