# How to remove line contains starting with NSLog iOS?

Tags: ios

I have NSLogs in code, so many time. A easy solution is that I replace with

```
NSLog(@  with //NSLog(@
```

But, If I want to remove all the lines, starting with NSLog, what can I do?

Thanks

Comment: see this link it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025471/do-i-need-to-disable-nslog-before-release-application

Comment: For the future consider to use breakpoint actions.

Comment: Breakpoint is different than NSLog. @vadian, its not necessory, we achieve all goals with breakpoints. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: A breakpoint *action* is more than a breakpoint. It's able to perform several tasks (logging is just one go them) without stopping. A major benefit is that it doesn't change the code. ⌥⌘-click on a breakpoint to see the settings popup.

Comment: @vadian, Great, wao, I am putting another question, for understanding this. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239377/breakpoint-debug-proper-usage-ios @vadian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode just search and replace from the Project Navigator. You can select "Starting with", "Contains", "Regular Expression", etc.

Using Regular Expression `^[\s\W]+NSLog.*$` should work well for lines that might have a tab or space before the `NSLog` but won't catch lines with other text that may be in front of it. (notice in the second screen shot `NSLog` was detected at the end of the line, while the first didn't).

Another example might be if you want to keep commented `NSLog` lines and remove the others:

```
^[^/*]*[\s\t]*NSLog.*$
```

Would remove `NSLog` on line 3 and `NSLog(@"%@",removed);` on line 7.

```
// NSLog
/* NSLog */
NSLog

NSString *NSLog = @"not nslog"

    NSLog(@"%@",removed);
```

**Additional Examples:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It will remove NSLog, not whole line of code @I'L'I

Comment: @VS: There's an option to use regular expressions as well... that allows the ability to remove the entire line. (See the bottom image).

Answer (score 1):

If your NSLogs are written in a single line, you can do a regex search and replace. Enter `NSLog.*$` as the search regex and replace it with an empty string. All your NSLog statements should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines to your ConvenienceMethods file:

```
#define SHOWLOGS NO
#defile NSLog if(SHOWLOGS)NSLog
```

If you don't have ConvenienceMethods file just write it on your controllers.